# fwrite to delete a row in a file

Tags: php, fwrite, delete-row

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove Line From CSV File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072015/remove-line-from-csv-file)

I have a file structured this way

```
numbers1;numbers;numbers;\n
numbers2;numbers;numbers;\n
numbers3 to delete;numbers;numbers;\n
numbers4;numbers;numbers;\n
```

If I want to delete the row containing "numbers3 to delete" (making the file:

```
numbers1;numbers;numbers;\n
numbers2;numbers;numbers;\n
numbers4;numbers;numbers;\n
```

) how can I use fwrite?

I did not find a "delete row" function, so I was thinking about counting the characters until \n, but still I couldn't find a way to do "delete this amount of characters".

Is there a "del" character?

Comment: This is effectively a CSV file, so you can use a solution from the question above. Googling `php csv delete row` has more

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
$filename = "filename.txt";
$handle = @fopen($filename, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 1096)) !== false) {
        if(!stripos($buffer, "numbers3 to delete")
            $somecontent .= $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

if (is_writable($filename)) {

    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'W+')) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }

    if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($somecontent) to file ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}
```

Comment: I have a question about $somecontent .= $buffer; What does it do?

Comment: $buffer will store each line and verify that it contain string "numbers3 to delete" or not. If it contain we will not concat it to $somecontent else $somecontent will continue to concate each line from your file.

Comment: Oh, so it's a multiple search?

Mmm and if I need only the first occorrence i just exit the while?

Comment: yes, It will search your text in each line. yes you are right!!!

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.
I'm still having problems because it just re-write the file as-is, when i'm done with the code I'll paste the final solution.

Comment: It's strange... It keeps failing in finding "numbers3 to delete" (i put an echo in an "else" case, and it never occurs.

Comment: Oh! !stripos returns null if there is no occurrence, else it returns 0. So, !stripos it's always true.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Suresh, I ended up with this (added a !== where needed, in the stripos part)

```
$eliminabile="numbers3 to delete;";

$handle = fopen("file.to.edit", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if(stripos($buffer, $eliminabile)!== 0)
        {
            $occorrenza .= $buffer;
        }
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

if (is_writable("file.to.edit")) {

    if (!$handle = fopen("file.to.edit", "w+")) {
         echo "Cannot open file";
         exit;
    }

    if (fwrite($handle, $occorrenza) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file";
        exit;
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($occorrenza) to file)";

    fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo "The file is not writable";
}


?>
```