# Remove line(s) from a CSV file and generate a new file automatically

Tags: php, fgetcsv, fputcsv

I am trying to manipulate an existing .csv file with PHP! I looked through most of the StackOverflow questions and I found [the answer from user "Myke Black"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8931692/4526506) which fits best for what I need.

I set `$id=2`, therefore I expect, that the code affects row 2 from my .csv file and a new generated .csv file without row 2 will be generated.

Here is my code:

```
$id=2;
$fptemp = fopen('files/FL_insurance_small-temp.csv', "a+");
if (($handle = fopen('files/FL_insurance_small.csv', "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($id= fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        if ($id != $data[0]) {
            $list = array($data);
            fputcsv($fptemp, $list);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($fptemp);

    rename('files/FL_insurance_small-temp.csv','files/output/FL_insurance_small_new.csv');
    echo "Row with ID: ".$id." successfully deleted!";
} else {
    print "There seems to be a problem.";
}
```

Everything seems to work fine cause a new file inside the output folder is generated. My problem is, that the new generated file is empty. Does anyone have an idea why? What am I missing?

Example data (.csv):

```
policyID,statecode,county,eq_site_limit,hu_site_limit,fl_site_limit,fr_site_limit,tiv_2011,tiv_2012,eq_site_deductible,hu_site_deductible,fl_site_deductible,fr_site_deductible,point_latitude,point_longitude,line,construction,point_granularity
119736,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",498960,498960,498960,498960,498960,792148.9,0,9979.2,0,0,30.102261,-81.711777,Residential,Masonry,1
448094,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",1322376.3,1322376.3,1322376.3,1322376.3,1322376.3,1438163.57,0,0,0,0,30.063936,-81.707664,Residential,Masonry,3
206893,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",190724.4,190724.4,190724.4,190724.4,190724.4,192476.78,0,0,0,0,30.089579,-81.700455,Residential,Wood,1
333743,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",0,79520.76,0,0,79520.76,86854.48,0,0,0,0,30.063236,-81.707703,Residential,Wood,3
172534,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",0,254281.5,0,254281.5,254281.5,246144.49,0,0,0,0,30.060614,-81.702675,Residential,Wood,1
785275,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",0,515035.62,0,0,515035.62,884419.17,0,0,0,0,30.063236,-81.707703,Residential,Masonry,3
995932,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",0,19260000,0,0,19260000,20610000,0,0,0,0,30.102226,-81.713882,Commercial,"Reinforced Concrete",1
223488,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",328500,328500,328500,328500,328500,348374.25,0,16425,0,0,30.102217,-81.707146,Residential,Wood,1
433512,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",315000,315000,315000,315000,315000,265821.57,0,15750,0,0,30.118774,-81.704613,Residential,Wood,1
142071,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",705600,705600,705600,705600,705600,1010842.56,14112,35280,0,0,30.100628,-81.703751,Residential,Masonry,1
253816,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",831498.3,831498.3,831498.3,831498.3,831498.3,1117791.48,0,0,0,0,30.10216,-81.719444,Residential,Masonry,1
894922,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",0,24059.09,0,0,24059.09,33952.19,0,0,0,0,30.095957,-81.695099,Residential,Wood,1
422834,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",0,48115.94,0,0,48115.94,66755.39,0,0,0,0,30.100073,-81.739822,Residential,Wood,1
582721,FL,"CLAY COUNTY",0,28869.12,0,0,28869.12,42826.99,0,0,0,0,30.09248,-81.725167,Residential,Wood,1
```

Comment: Where is `$data` defined?

Comment: Thank you Patrick. That seems to be the problem, you are right. Can you tell me how I need to change the code so $data is defined? I am stucked on the code I posted.

Comment: I can't tell you because I'm not sure what you're intending `$data` to be.  Maybe you mean `$data = fgetcsv($handle)`?

Comment: Why develop an application in PHP to do a task like this? You *really* don't want to use flat files as a database. And if its a one-off, a text editor or a one-liner shell script would have been much faster and easier to debug.

Comment: @symcbean I have 500+ .csv files where the lines 3-8 should be removed. It is the same for every file. Therefore a simple php script should be the fastest way in my opinion. There may be better ways but PHP is actually the programming language I know. :)

Comment: So a two line shell script then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading the file - your overwriting `$id` which is the row your looking for.  Instead your loop should assign the value to `$data` instead...

```
$rowcount = 1;
while ($data= fgetcsv($handle)) {
    if ($id != $rowcount++) {
        fputcsv($fptemp, $data);
    }
}
```

`$rowCount` is the row that is currently being read and so this is compared against each row as it reads the new line in.

This also removes the redundant assignment to `$list`.

To 'delete'(or ommit) a list of records...

```
$id= [2,5,7];
$rowcount = 1;
while ($data= fgetcsv($handle)) {
    if (!in_array($rowcount++, $id)) {   // Only write row if not in the list
        fputcsv($fptemp, $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Your updated code seems to work cause within the new created file, the data from the edited .csv file are inserted. Problem now is that the code makes no effect. I get the message "Row with ID: 2 successfully deleted!" but inside the new file, row 2 is still there. Any ideay why?

Comment: @ChristophC. Please put the sample data directly into your question (not a link).

Comment: oh okay. I do not want to remove the row with the specific ID. I want to remove the second row from the file. So $id should not be the ID, instead it should be the row from the file. If I enter $id=234 than the script should remove the line 234 from the .csv file. This is what I am looking for to do.

Comment: amazing. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much Nigel. I will mark your answer as the correct answer. Just one last question: Is it possible to delete more than one row at once? If so, can you tell me what my code should look like. For example: I want to delete line 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 from the .csv file. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @ChristophC. Just a small point, you're not actually _deleting_ those lines. You are _omitting_ them from the content written to the new file.

Comment: I understand what you mean @Nigel Ren. Changing the $id to an array is not a problem. I just do not understand where do I need to place the if-statement? Is it after the $rowcount=1 and around the while-function? Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: Thanks @Patrik Q. I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Nigel Ren: I tried your newly added code but it is not working. Output .csv file still contains the rows. My $id= [3,4,5,6,7,8];! Have you tried it? Is it working at your end?

Comment: The `$rowcount++` is missing from the new version.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickQ, I'd added it to the test and forgot to change the code here.

Comment: @NigelRen and Patrick Q: thank you. Now it is working as it should. I really appreciate your help. Have a nice day